# EF delete database between tests

Tags: c#, specflow

I'm writing tests for my UI using Specflow. Some tests change my database so i can't rerun some tests. As i'm using EF, i've decided to simply delete my database (because EF will create new one and seed it). While i'm running my tests, my MVC project is open. I tried to delete my database with this code:

```
[BeforeFeature]
public static void DropDatabase()
{
    Database.Delete("SampleDbName");
}
```

But the problem is that i'm getting Cannot drop database because it is currently in use.
Then i tried two solutions :

1. Add Pooling = false to my connections string
2. Call SqlConnection.ClearAllPools(); before deleting my database

Both cases didn't work for me because i'm getting "cannot attach the file .mdf as database" error each time i'm trying to access my database (this happens after my database is deleted).
My goal is to make my tests rerunable without restarting my MVC project. Is there some solutions to solve this problem ?

Comment: .Net Core or Framework ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall framework (EF 6)

Comment: Ideally, you'd mock a db, instead of actually manipulating one. Any reason you aren't doing that?

Comment: Try mocking as Austin wrote in pair with Unit Test project in VS. Also why do you want to delete whole database? Wouldn't truncate be enough? In EF you can delete all entities with Clear()

Comment: @AustinTFrench i used to mock database in unit tests, but i have to work with real database now

Comment: @jojess i don't need empty tables for testing it, actually i need to just update few entities to continue work with them. If my database not created, first time i try to access it it will be created and seeded with some records i need

Comment: What I meant is instead of dropping database (that you can't do once the app is running) and reseed it just do truncate and reseed.

Comment: If you are using SpecFlow to write full integration tests then the application will likely need a real database. Both the test runner and the application could be holding connections open, which will prevent the database from deleting things. You might be better off writing a stored procedure that deletes data from tables instead.